# WPF RichTextBox: SelectionOpacity while not focused

Tags: wpf, focus, selection, richtextbox, highlight

Is it possible to make WPF 4.0 RichTextEdit display it's Selection while not focused?
By default, the selection highlighting rectangle disappears when RichTextEdit loses focus.

The following natually does not work.

```
<RichTextBox>

    <RichTextBox.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type RichTextBox}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="false">
                    <Setter Property="SelectionOpacity" Value="1"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </RichTextBox.Style>

    <FlowDocument>
        <Paragraph>
            <Run>Example Text</Run>
        </Paragraph>
    </FlowDocument>

</RichTextBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to handle the `LostFocus` event to prevent the selection to be removed.

xaml:

```
<RichTextBox LostFocus="RichTextBox_OnLostFocus" />
```

code behind:

```
void RichTextBox_OnLostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var rtb = e.Source as RichTextBox;
    if (rtb == null)
        return;

    if (!rtb.Selection.Start.Equals(rtb.Selection.End))
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but for anyone looking for an answer in future - any controls inheriting from TextBoxBase have a *IsInactiveSelectionHighlightEnabled* property.

If you set this property as true, selected text will remain highlighted when the containing control has lost focus (though the colour brush used is different).

This should cover WPF RichTextBox or FlowDocumentReader.